# Order by time stored as Varchar

Tags: oracle, to-date, to-char

I have  a column(s_time) as varchar. I store 12 hours time(7:00 AM). I want  to order by this  column(s_time).
I tried  with this oracle  query

```
select * from tabl_time order by to_date('s_time','hh12:mi') asc
```

But  this  did not  work.
Can anyone  help me  doing  this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly did not work? Do you have an error message?

Comment: No error  message, but the column data is not in order

Comment: Can you put some test data?

Comment: I want  to sort by the  s_time column. s-time has time(like 07:00 AM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to be missing the AM / PM part in your format, which can be represented by AM or PM (or in doc also by A.M. or P.M. but I have some problems with the dot version in fiddle at least)

```
select * from table_time 
order by to_date(s_time, 'HH12:MI AM') asc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
to_date('s_time','HH12:MI AM') ASC
```